# Programically change Dynamic Text instead of having to go to Settings

Tags: ios, accessibility, settings

In iOS, Is there a way to programically change System Wide, Dynamic Text instead of having to go to Settings? I am working on a demo application to gather support this feature and I haven't found a way yet. Maybe a Notification?

I haven't found a way yet.

Comment: No. In general apps cannot change device-wide settings.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can open "Developer Documentation" which includes each API in iOS SDK, from Xcode > Help menu.  When I searched some terms for dynamic type, I just found a read-only methods. For the settings defined in the Settings app, an application can ask its app-related permissions for a first time. After the rejection, apps should redirect user to give permission manually. So even a lot of settings cannot be opened with a deeplink. (Only notification and App Setting page can be opened with deeplink.)

Answer (score -1):

There is a bit you can do to system-wide text; here's a rundown. [(All information I am describing below comes from Apple's Typography Guidelines)](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/typography)

First, it is meant to be "convenient and consistent" across the device. Apple wants the user to feel comfortable with the text used throughout the device. That is the motivation for decreasing the control of the developer.

Second, you can modify some aspects of system-wide font. "System APIs define font adjustments — *called symbolic traits*," which give you a fair bit of power to modify the system-wide text. To do so, you can check out the documentation for [`leading(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/leading(_:)).

All of this is for working with a system-wide font in-app. You are unable to change system-wide settings and affect a user's experience outside of your app.